# Call to a member function download () on null error in laravel

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to download a PDF in the browser but I am getting this error

```
Call to a member function download () on null
```

This is the code:

```
public function index(){
  $data ="<h1>Welcome</h1>";
  $content= PDF::loadView('PDF.invoice', $data);
 return $content->download('invoice.PDF');
}
```

I have tried `save('invoice.PDF')` and `Output('invoice.PDF')` instead of `download('invoice.PDF')` but it keeps showing `member function download () on null`. Anyone can solve this problem?

Comment: You have to show more code. Obviously your `$content` is `null` but what does `PDF::loadView` do?

Comment: As its says you don't have any object in $content, its null, its not the method  call that is causing the error, find out why $content is null, pdf::loadView would be a good start

Comment: Maybe it is something similar to this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dompdf-not-loading-data-to-view